# Python - Reverse-engineering "%" (modulus)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, modulus

I have an algorithm that takes 2 inputs; "x" and "y". x is a number from 1 to 250 and y is either a positive or a negative integer. Does anyone know if there is way to get all of the possible values of x and y; if the only number that is known is "c"?

```
x = {a number from 1 to 250}
a = y * 11
b = a + x
c = b % 43
```

Comment: This sounds like a question for puzzle SO :).

Comment: is y defined the same as x? or y can be anything?

Comment: @JoranBeasley y can be anything

Comment: This belongs in https://math.stackexchange.com/ since it is a maths based problem. Coding in Python isn't the question or the desired answer; it simply does the calculations.

Answer (score 2):

If `a = y * 11` then `b = y * 11 + x`. So `c = (y * 11 + x) % 43` => There's no way because modulo is *irreversible*. You can look on [Math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com), I'm sure there are some people figuring out how to revert the modulo operator.

Answer (score 2):

assuming that x is bound from 1-250

lets assume C is 5

that means `(y*11)+x = 5,48,91,134,...,infinty`

`((y*11)+x)%43 = 5`

so one answer to this would be `y=0;x=5 or 48 or 91 ... 215`

- now let `y = 1` then `11+x = 48 or 91 ot 134,...215`
- now let `y = -1` then `-11+x = 5 or 48 or 91 or ... 215`

as you can see there is no correct solution to this problem (or rather infinite correct solutions)